# Autoplay attribute gives an error with iframe (youtube)

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am experiencing an autoplay error while trying to put a yt video within 'iframe'.
So basically i have the feeling it's because of the div but have no idea how to prevent it.
The whole idea is the following - When I click onto that div - (called play), the yt video might just start instead of clicking twice of course.
However here is the html and jQuery code:

```
<div class="video">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9EcjYs8.jpg" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OgAr66JbvtU autoplay=1"/>
    <div class="play"><i class="icon-play"> ► </i></div>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$('.play').click(function () {
    video = '<iframe width="600" height="375" frameborder="0" src="' + $('img').attr('data-video') + '"></iframe>';
    $('.video').replaceWith(video);
});
});
```

P.S.
I can provide you with the .css code too.
Here you go:

```
body{
  background-image: linear-gradient(#99ccff, #fff6e4);
}

html{
  min-height:100%;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    height: 375px;
    width: 600px;
    background: #73AF96;
    position: absolute;
}
.video img {
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.play {
    opacity:0.5;
    height: 100px;
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*Centering*/
    margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    background: #FF9933;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
    color: white;
}
.play:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    background: #FF6600;
}
.icon-play {
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size:2.5em;
}

.icon-play:before {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: missing the `?` in the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@Chimoo already answered this:*  you need a '?' between the embed/OgAr66JbvtU and autoplay=1.

[JSBin ya dig](http://jsbin.com/EWELeyE/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

**Here's what we mean:**

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/9EcjYs8.jpg" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OgAr66JbvtU?autoplay=1"/>
```

Also, move your `<div class="play">...</div>` to go before your `<img>` and add this to your css for some fun!  :)

```
.video img {
  opacity: 0.65;  
  transition: 0.4s all;
}
.video div.play:hover + img {
  filter: blur(3px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
.play {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I got it now ^^ . Thanks!

Comment: yay.  I hope you took my very amazing CSS to heart haha

Comment: Yep, it looks even more great now ^_^. Thanks again. :)